# Why are users with negative score ranked higher than users with zero score in Collectives' leaderboards?

Tags: bug, status-completed, collectives

On the various user leaderboards within a Collective, users are ranked based on the amount of reputation earned on the Collective's tags in a certain period of time (weekly, monthly, yearly). However, I see that users with a negative score are ranked higher than some of the other users that have a score of zero. This seems counter-intuitive.

Example from the [current Intel Collective monthly leaderboard](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/intel?tab=members&TimeSpanFilter=Month&Page=1):

[image: screenshot]

How's that so? Is this a bug?

Comment: i think he lost only rep though some bounties, that don't count

Comment: seems like quite a useful leaderboard, if it considers people who've earned nothing leaders

Comment: @KevinB yeah I mean, those leaderboards are pretty laughable, though it's weird to see someone that only posted an unhelpful answer ranked higher than others that didn't. If you want to implement a leaderboard at least do it correctly...

Comment: @nbk the user at -2 definitely did not lose rep through a bounty though, it's a simple downvote. Also, seems pretty weird to count rep lost through bounties TBH, it probably shouldn't be counted in such a leaderboard, makes it look like offering bounties is somehow "bad".

Comment: @MarcoBonelli subjct-x has a bounty on his post oif 225, and also you basically can't loos 438 points per fownvote, which would mean 219 downvotes, nobody gets so many downvotes at one time or even pne day

Comment: @nbk yeah of course, that user offered a bounty. I was just saying that the one right above only got a single downvote.

Comment: that is because the scrips had not run at that time, and the servers had today massive problems, so it could take some time till all is "normal" again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the future, we will move the negative scores to below the zero scores. The leaderboard is also the Collective members list, so that's why everyone is shown somewhere.

---

**UPDATE:**
This change has been made. Additionally, rep changes from bounties offered or cancelled bounties are no longer included as part of the rep calculation for the collective leaderboard.