# Only honor reputation earned on open pages when calculating Collection Leaderboard scores

Tags: feature-request, status-review, reputation, collectives, leaderboard

In recent months, I've observed a revitalized energy to answer new low-hanging fruit duplicate (and otherwise closable) questions tagged with [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php).

I am a Recognized Member of the PHP Collective and I too often find that the contributors who are earning the Top 3 trophies in this collective are farming rep from pages that are later closed. These users have the privilege, knowledge and experience to vote to close, but are failing to prioritize the platform goals over rep accumulation.

## Feature Request:

- When calculating Collective leaderboard scores, do not include positive rep changes from posts on closed pages where **the question was asked since the start of the Collective**.

In other words, the maximum points you can earn (**with respect to the Collective leaderboard only**) from posting on a closed question is 0.  If your post has a negative score, those negative values will be applied to the Collective leaderboard calculation.

This should be a resounding micro-step toward encouraging contributors to stop answering new closable questions without bringing the universal gamification of the platform to a grinding halt.

If Collective Members want to earn that shiny trophy, they'll need to:

- ask unique, on-topic questions or
- post their unique answers on on-topic questions and dupe targets -- instead of just racing to answer.

These trophies are the latest "big shiny thing" on pages and inexperienced users are likely to follow the contribution habits of these award winners.  Let's, finally, do something to encourage responsible contributions.

Comment: Well, Stack Overflow is approaching its 16th birthday, right?  If it can drive a car in the US, then it can start making its bed, right?

Comment: I don't think withholding score would actually deter future users from participating in this way, given 1: it wouldn't be clear up front that they'd even lose the rep/position, and 2: even if that's a possibility, the most effective way to increase the number is to increase the quantity, quality being irrelevant generally because wins are worth more than losses. But, by all means, have the leaderboard reflect actual scores and not have someone with 0 undeleted answers recently in #1.

Comment: The fundamental goal: [The fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates#:~:text=The%20fundamental%20goal%20of%20closing%20duplicate%20questions%20is%20to%20help%20people%20find%20the%20right%20answer%20by%20getting%20all%20of%20those%20answers%20in%20one%20place.)  This feature will be a low-disruption way of showing favor to curation. A box can be added to closed pages explaining the feature's rule if desirable.

Comment: I might be missing something but how do they post on closed questions? Or do you mean if the question is closed _after_ they post? If so, it might be tricky to retroactively calculate the score

Comment: FGITW answerers often get to the low-hanging fruit before we do, Phil. Off-topic or duplicate pages are closed, but the posts still gets those yummy, yummy unicorn points with absolutely no incentive to curate.  So they just rinse and repeat.  They don't care if the page is closed or off-topic -- they just want to answer.  Some times there are 3 or 4 upvoted answers (on the lowest hanging fruit) before the page is closed.  The Collective Leaderboard scores are calculated once per day -- filtering will be simple -- if the question is newer than the Collective and closed, exclude post reps.

Comment: I'm not sure most FGITW posters care about score - they have huge rep because they answer so much, not necessarily the other way around. More critically, I would not trust them to not just reopen the questions if they do care. There’s entire subtags where I refrain from duplicate closure because I know that specific answerers will just unhammer them anyway. Then again, maybe it would be helpful to make these silent conflicts more overt…

Comment: The gold trophy user that was using AI only had ~200 rep so far.  FGITW users come in all shapes and sizes.  At some point, Stack Overflow needs to devise a plan (or plans) to steer the community toward better curation (perhaps a blend of "carrot" and "stick").

Comment: I upvoted, because I think the spirit is right. But unfortunately, even if implemented, it won't fix the problem. Sadly it's much easier to answer a simple duplicate than finding the duplicate target. As you know, there is no incentive to close duplicates and only disincentive because people complain to you in the comments. Second, there is approximately zero chance Stack Overflow (the company) would implement this because they seem most focused on "retention" metrics these days. If someone does your home or work task quickly, why not come back? Sorry, I'm pretty cynical.

Comment: This feature may not create mass behavioral change, but if it even gets a few regular contributors to recalibrate their activities a little bit, then it will be worth it.  Baby steps.

Answer (score 2):

At this time we do not have plans to adjust the reputation calculations for Collectives leaderboards. We have noted several feature requests in this area ([here is another fairly recent one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426952/)), but as with that one, we'll assess this request when we return development focus to the leaderboard and other incentives within Collectives. Changes are not out of the question — we did modify the calculation to [exclude bounty-related changes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/419608/18279858) in the past. As you noted, in the future this need could also be addressed by sitewide improvements to incentives for better curation.